# How to write a named pipe server using f# to server many clients?

Tags: f#

I have write a f# named pipe server:

```
let a=new NamedPipeServerStream("a")
a.WaitForConnection()
let reader=new StreamReader(a)

let rec loop()=
    let b=reader.ReadLine()
    match b with 
    |b' when String.IsNullOrEmpty(b')->()
    |_->
        Console.WriteLine b
        loop()

loop()
```

This server can work,but for only one client.When client is quit,the server quit too.

How can I write a named pipe server,like tcp server,that can server many clients,and never stop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the C# example here [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085(v=vs.110).aspx) you need to read from the NamedPipeServerStream using multiple threads to service multiple clients (consider using Async methods in the loop function). The following example can service up to 4 clients at the same time.

```
let MaxPipes = 4

let pipe = new NamedPipeServerStream("a", PipeDirection.InOut,MaxPipes)
let rec loop () = async{
  pipe.WaitForConnection()
  let reader = new StreamReader(pipe)
  let b = reader.ReadLine()
  return! loop ()
}

for i in [1..MaxPipes] do
  Async.Start (loop ())
```

Comment: Thanks.But when I start the program,It's quit quickly.Is there something wrong?

Comment: To prevent your Console app from exiting you need something at the end to block like a Console.ReadLine ().